# Can Flask async route handler work with this async call?

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio

My goal is to use `gql.transport.aiohttp.AIOHTTPTransport` to query data when handling a Flask route.

I'm relying on `fetch_schema_from_transport=True` which downloads the schema each time the session is recreated, so I'd like to reuse a single session across multiple requests. (Unless this is discouraged.)

Here's an example implementation:

```py
import asyncio

from flask import Flask
from gql import Client, gql
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport

token = 'bearer ...'  # GitHub API token


async def main():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url='https://api.github.com/graphql',
                                 headers={'Authorization': token})
    client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)
    async with client as session:
        @app.route('/')
        async def home():
            query = gql('''
            query example ($username: String!) {
                user(login: $username){
                    bio,
                }
            }
            ''')
            params = {
                'username': 'octocat'
            }
            result = await session.execute(query, variable_values=params)
            return result

        app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Unfortunately when I query `GET /` I get this error:

> `RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<AIOHTTPTransport.execute() running at .../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gql/transport/aiohttp.py:208> cb=[_release_waiter(<Future pendi...ask_wakeup()]>)() at /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.0_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:387]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop`

I can switch this around to instantiate a new `Client` on each call to `/`, but this seems like it would be wasteful. Below is an example that avoids the error:

```py
async def main():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url='https://api.github.com/graphql',
                                 headers={'Authorization': token})

    @app.route('/')
    async def home():
        query = gql('''
        query example ($username: String!) {
            user(login: $username){
                bio,
            }
        }
        ''')
        params = {
            'username': 'octocat'
        }
        client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)
        async with client as session:
            result = await session.execute(query, variable_values=params)
            return result

    app.run()
```

Is there a good way to make the first code sample work without recreating the session for each request?

Answer (score 1):

I realized in my case that the schema is cached in the `Client`, so the following implementation only fetches the schema once:

```py
async def main():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url='https://api.github.com/graphql',
                                 headers={'Authorization': token})
    client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)

    @app.route('/')
    async def home():
        query = gql('''
        query example ($username: String!) {
            user(login: $username){
                bio,
            }
        }
        ''')
        params = {
            'username': 'octocat'
        }
        async with client as session:
            result = await session.execute(query, variable_values=params)
            return result

    app.run()
```